# Angular: How to find particular object in the .html file?

Tags: angular

How to find perticular object in the .html page?

```
data = {
    "zipCode": "40000",
    "county": "Srilanka",
    "state": "Northen",
    "specilityData": [
        {
            "specialty": "North",
            "specialtyCount": 1,
            "specialtyRepresentation": 9411
        },
        {
            "specialty": "South",
            "specialtyCount": 4,
            "specialtyRepresentation": 3323
        },
        {
            "specialty": "East",
            "specialtyCount": 1,
            "specialtyRepresentation": 0
        },
        ............................
        ............................
    ]
}
```

The data displayed in the .html file and we needed that particular "specilityData" details. How is it possible to get that data in .html?

```
<span class="card-field-values"> {{data?.specilityData.find(({ specialty }) => specialty === "North")?.specialtyCount}} </span>
```

This code throw the error in .html file. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there's multiple options. Here's a couple examples of ways using like a method or `*ngFor` you can play with [in a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5scy8c) but the gist is either like for example with a method;

```
getSpecialty = (spec: string):any =>
    this.data?.specilityData.find(({ specialty }) => specialty === spec)
      ?.specialtyCount;
```

and in the HTML with binding;

```
{{ getSpecialty('North') }}
```

Or with *ngFor;

```
<span class="card-field-values" *ngFor="let data of data.specilityData">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.specialty === 'North'">
    <!-- {{data.specialty}}<br> -->
    {{ data.specialtyCount }}<br />
    <!-- {{data.specialtyRepresentation}} -->
  </ng-container>
</span>
```

Or other ways depending what you're really trying to do, hope this helps and welcome to SO.

Comment: ```{{ getSpecialty('North') }}`` Is it possible to call multi time in the .html file?

Comment: @Gowsegan If you want just that one value then I'd assign it to a public var in the ts and just reference it directly if it's used a lot, otherwise yea it just returns the result of the arg each time whereas assigning it to a public var just finds the value once and provides a reference. So like in the OnInit you'd just do like `this.yourPublicVar = this.getSpeciality('North');` and then in your html just `{{ yourPublicVar }} {{ yourPublicVar }} {{ yourPublicVar }}`